# How to properly pass many dependencies (external APIs) to a class in Scala?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, dependencies

How to properly pass many dependencies (external APIs) to a class in Scala?

I'm working on the application that uses many APIs to collect data. For API's I have `trait` like below.

```
trait api {
  def url: Foo
  def parse: Bar
}
```

Also, there are about 10 implementations of the `api` trait (one for each API). Inside a parent actor, I want to create a child actor for every external API. I created new trait and implementation,

```
trait ExternalApis {
  val apiList: List[api]
}

object MyApis extends ExternalApis {
  val apiList = List(new ApiImpl1, ..., new ApiImpl10)
}
```

so now I can pass `MyApis` object (or any other implementation of `ExternalApis`) to parent actor and map over `apiList` for creating such child actors.

It seems to me I'm missing something. Are there more proper ways to do it?

Comment: Looks good to me. If you need more flexibility you could read the list of api implementations from a config file or db, but that would also result in higher complexity.

Comment: The only problem I see is: how do you know to which API implementation dispatch the message? I don't know your entire codebase so sorry if it seems a silly question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation that you have made looks *nearly* ready. Just something I would like to add are:

1. Passing an API List may not be the most ideal way to do such a thing. Anytime you would like to add/remove something to the API list, you would have to change different areas of the code. A suggestion would be to read this from a config folder, where the config folders would contain things such as url, username, password etc.

If you could provide more insight on the usage of these API's, it would help my answer a lot.

Hope this helped!

Comment: All APIs are open and returning some prices. I need to create implementations of `api` trait for each API, as there is _very_ different logic of getting prices and external info from each API. And I don't see how it should be done inside the configuration file. Should I create something like  `apiList=[classpath1, .., classpath10]` and then load it?

Comment: Yes, that is also a good implementation. The loading of the url, username and password should be defined and loaded from the config file.